# Adding params to redirect_uri in oAuth DoorKeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

I am using DoorKeeper gem to create API from my Rails app. By default, DoorKeeper will return to my client's url with a param `code="123"` as follow:

```
http://localhost:3001/api/callback?code="123"
```

I would like to pass additional params, i.e., `user_id` and `token` as follow:

```
http://localhost:3001/api/callback?code="123"&user_id="3"&token"abc"
```

Is it possible with DoorKeeper?

Comment: Here are a few posts regarding issues you might stumble upon.. see this might help https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/?s=doorkeeper

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be off OAuth2 spec with this. Most consumers would use a lib for OAuth2 and then this wouldn't be supported.

You are supposed to provide those values in an API that the other service can call when it's got the access_tokens

```
module API
 module V1
  class UsersController < ApplicationController::Base
    respond_to :json
    def show
      respond_with User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id).some_info_as_json
    end
  end
end
```

That's the OAuth2 way and we both may not like it too much:) What did you end up doing?